# I'm creating a random array in PHP and my code doesnt seem to output a truly random answer

Tags: php, arrays, random

I want to construct an array of 3 offers that output in a random order. I have the following code and whilst it does output 3 random offers it doesn't appear to be random. The first value in the generated array always seems to be from the 1st 2 records in my offers table. The offers table only has 5 records in it (I dont know if this is affecting things).

```
$arrayOfferCount = $offerCount-1;
$displayThisManyOffers = 3;

$range = range(0, $arrayOfferCount);
$vals = array_rand($range, $displayThisManyOffers);`
```

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: http://www.etoan.com/random-number-generation/dilbert2001182781025.gif

Comment: Humans are good at detecting patterns, even where none exist. array_rand will generate random numbers, but since you've got only got 5 things to randomize, it'll look like there's patterns where there aren't any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that [mt_rand()](http://php.net/mt_rand) is much better PRNG.

However, in your case you need to let the database select them for you

```
SELECT * FROM ads ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 3
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Made life so much easier and stripped about 20 lines of code out. Thansk again !

Comment: Be aware that ORDER BY RAND() has the potential to be really slow if the table gets big or the query gets more complex. For this situation it is a great choice, as you only have 5 records.

Comment: Thanks for the info about this solution potentialy being slow...what sort of table size should I be concerned about - my guess is that this table will never have more than abbout 500 records - do you think this will represent an issue ?

Comment: No, I think he means once you start getting millions of records. The type of row also effects this. However, the best thing when testing database design is to load it up with sample rows to make sure everything is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Working fine here. Benchmark it over lots of runs instead of just gut feeling... here it is for 1,000 tries:

```
<?php

$offerCount = 5;
$arrayOfferCount = $offerCount-1;
$displayThisManyOffers = 3;

$range = range(0, $arrayOfferCount);

for($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
    $vals = array_rand($range, $displayThisManyOffers);

    foreach($vals as $val) {
        $counts[$val]++;
    }
}

sort($counts);
print_r($counts);
```

Generates:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 583
    [1] => 591
    [2] => 591
    [3] => 610
    [4] => 625
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably randomly picking which to display, but displaying them in the same order they appear in your array.  If you do it enough times (~20) you should get the third one to show up once if this is the case (chances of choosing exactly the last 3 out of 5 would be 1 in 5*4, so around every 20th one you'll see the third option appear).

Comment: thanks for your thoughts any idea how I can rewrite this code to make it more random...or even favour those offers that appear later in the table...the opposite of what I appear to have at the moment

Answer (score 0):

array_rand seems not to work properly sometimes (see PHP-Manual comments).

Workaround: Get the array size and pick a random index using the function [mt_rand](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php)